# Make Rest API request to kubernetes service that is not exposed via Python kubernetes client

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

In my Kubernetes cluster, I have a service running

```
kubectl get -n test svc
NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
dummy-svc                           ClusterIP   10.245.72.218   <none>        9001/TCP,9003/TCP,9090/TCP   25h
```

Which acts as a REST API, so, for instance, I could use some port-forward and run something like

```
curl http://localhost:9090/test \
  -d name="abcd" \
  -d region="EU1" ​\
 ​-G
```

and it works nicely.

When I try to run a GET request to this REST API via the Kubernetes Python client, it looks as follows:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config("~/.kube/config", context="my-remote-cluster")


api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
name = 'dummy-svc'
namespace = 'test'
path = 'test?name=abcd&region=EU1'

api_response = api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_service_proxy(name, namespace, path=path)
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 1535, in connect_get_namespaced_service_proxy
    return self.connect_get_namespaced_service_proxy_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 1622, in connect_get_namespaced_service_proxy_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 348, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 180, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 373, in request
    return self.rest_client.GET(url,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 240, in GET
    return self.request("GET", url,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 234, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (503)
Reason: Service Unavailable
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '4b051acd-6254-4661-b03a-a1cd82321311', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 24 Jan 2022 22:30:44 GMT', 'Content-Length': '184'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"no endpoints available for service \"dummy-svc\"","reason":"ServiceUnavailable","code":503}
```

Of course, I tried many different variations of it (particularly for the path), but so far I have not managed to find a way to access the REST API via the Kubernetes Python client.

Can you help me here for making that happen? If there is a completely different way you suggest, I would be happy to get to know about it.

Comment: `no endpoints available for service` implies the Service object is misconfigured; its selectors don't match the labels of the pod you want to connect to.

Comment: You're also calling `config.load_incluster_config()` in your initial setup, which is a little surprising.  If this code is running in the same Kubernetes cluster as the service, you can directly call `http://dummy-svc.test:9090` without going through the Kubernetes API (again, subject to the service being correctly configured); see [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry for it, it is indeed another cluster, but I wanted to make it as concise as possible. I amended it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The strange thing is, if I go with port-forward, it works like a charm. So why is this causing some problem here?

Comment: What's the actual `kubectl port-forward` command you're running?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is `kubectl port-forward --namespace test service/dummy-svc 9090`

Comment: Where do you run this Python script?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same thing and subsequently had the same issue. I was wondering why it also worked with rancher's UI until I spotted what the URL there actually looks like:

`https://rancher.my.domain/k8s/clusters/my-cluster/api/v1/namespaces/cattle-monitoring-system/services/http:rancher-monitoring-grafana:80/proxy/`

It's not just the service name but `<protocol>:<service-name>:<port>`.

So the correct code would be (assuming your service is running HTTP on port 80):

```py
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
name = 'http:dummy-svc:80'
namespace = 'test'
path = 'test?name=abcd&region=EU1'
api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_service_proxy(name, namespace, path=path)
```